# Alternative data structure - Preventing memory leak in ios5 with ARC

Tags: ios5, data-structures, memory-leaks, linked-list, automatic-ref-counting

I have a data structure I am trying to store in objective c for ios5 with ARC.
The data structure is something like -

```
Class - **Book**
@property (strong) NSArray *pages;
@property (strong) Page *startingPage;

Class - **Page**
@property (strong) Book *book;
@property (strong) Page *nextPage;
@property (strong) Page *previousPage;
```

The problem as can be imagined is with memory leaks.
There are a couple of cycles here -

```
Book -> pages -> page -> book
nextPage -> previousPage
Book -> startingPage -> book.
```

I can't make the properties weak because if I do so, I'll lose the pointer to that value.
So suppose I make *book* in **Page** as weak, then when I try to deallocate a page, book will get deallocated. However, I still want the book to remain allocated.

Is there any alternate way this data structure can be stored?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand why making Page->book `weak` would lose you the pointer to the book. Weak properties aren't auto-nil'd until the object they point to is deallocated. As long as at least one other object has a strong reference to `book` you should be fine.

So imagine a Library object that has an NSArray of books. The array retains the books added to it, so all weak references to that book will stay valid until the book's removed from the array (and implicitly released).

Comment: But what if there is no other strong pointer to 'book'? So say in your example, if all the NSArray of books have a weak reference to Library, then Library will get nil'ed out since there is no strong reference to it. The only way to do that would be for each book to have a strong reference to Library, and there lies the problem.

Comment: @Devang I'm struggling to think of a scenario in which all references to an object are weak. No object is an island -- there really ought to be *something* that claims ownership of it. If there's not, that's more than likely a sign of bad design. What object is responsible for book? Can you explain why you don't want it to have a strong reference to it?

Comment: You are right, I can keep a strong reference to the objects which will guarantee that the rest of the references will behave as expected. Thanks!